# Integral over a product of two Green's functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration, complex-numbers, greens-functions

Need some help here on a frequently encountered integral in Green's function formalism. Forgive me since I am a junior student.

I have an integral/summation as a product of a retarded and advanced Green's functions, looks simply like 
$$\sum_{p^{\prime}}\frac{1}{p^{2}-{p^{\prime}}^{2}-i\epsilon}\frac{1}{p^{2}-{p^{\prime}}^{2}+i\epsilon}$$
where I have omitted the mass $m$ to make the notation simple; $\epsilon$ is a positive infinitesimal.

I can convert the summation to an integral over momentum $p$ or energy, this is standard. Then I follow the complex analysis and identify 4 poles (if the integration is over momentum) and further apply the residue theorem. But, what I get is an expression proportional to $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. This means it is divergent since $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Could any one please point out to me what have I missed in this calculation? What mistakes did I make? Many many thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could present the 'calculations' you refer to.

Comment: This is actually the calculation I have to do. A product of a retarded and an advanced Green's functions (or propagator), for which I have to sum over the $p^{\prime}$.

Comment: [Related post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339357/fourier-transform-of-the-free-propagator-squared-int-d4p-frace-i-p-c/339366#339366).

Answer (score 1):

In general one can write

\begin{equation}
 G^R_{k_1}(z)\;
G^A_{k_2}(z)=\frac{G^R_{k_1}(z)-G^A_{k_2}(z)}{\varepsilon_{k_1}-\varepsilon_{k_2}},
 \end{equation}

This way you can perform the integral easily.
Take a look at Economou's book on Green's functions...