# Fourier transform of the free propagator squared - $\int d^{4}p\ \frac{e^{-i p\cdot x}}{p^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon}$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, propagator

The point of the question is to ask what is the function given by the following integral:
$$
H(x,y) \ \equiv \ \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{-i p \cdot (x-y)}}{(p^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon)^{2}}
$$

This is closely related to the propagator (for $(x-y)^{2} < 0$):
$$
G(x,y) \ = \ \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{-i p \cdot (x-y)}}{p^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon} \ = \ - \frac{ i m }{ 4 \pi^{2} \sqrt{ - (x-y)^{2} }} K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ - (x-y)^{2} } \right)
$$

The reason I ask this question, is because in calculations like for the following Feynman diagram:

[image]

I would have in position space the following:
$$
\propto \int d^{4}u\ G_{0}(x,u) G_{0}(u,u) G_{0}(u,y)\\
= \int d^{4}u \left[ \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{-i p \cdot (x-u)}}{p^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon} \right] \left[ \int \frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{1}{k^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon} \right] \left[ \int \frac{d^{4}q}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{-i p \cdot (u-y)}}{q^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon} \right] \\
= \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{e^{-i p \cdot (x-y)}}{(p^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon)^{2}} \ \int \frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{1}{k^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon} \\
= H(x,y) \int \frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{1}{k^{2}+m^{2}-i\epsilon}
$$

You can regulate the integral over $k$ however you like, but what to do with $H(x,y)$ here?

It seems that $H(x,y)$ pops up a lot when you do calculations like this. Is there a way to evaluate $H(x,y)$? Surely this must have been done somewhere?

Comment: FYI, you're missing a delta function on the light cone in the propagator. See [Wikipedia's Feynman propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you don't need to go through the Fourier transform to get the result you're seeking. All you need is translation invariance of $G$ (i.e. $G(x,y) = G(x+w, y+w) = G(|x-y|)$) to say that the first integral gives:
\begin{align}
I & \equiv \int \operatorname{d}^4 u \ G_0(x,u)\, G_0(u,u)\, G_0(u,y) \\
& = G(0) \int \operatorname{d}^4 u \ G_0(x,u)\, G_0(u,y),
\end{align}
as long as the Green's function $G$ has been suitably regularized to make $G(0)$ finite. Note that the convolution chain can grow infinitely long. Consider an exactly solvable perturbation of the form $\Delta \mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{2}(\Delta m^2) \phi^2$, you'll get just such an infinite chain in producing the net propagator with shifted mass.

One way to calculate $H$ is to note that it can be produced by the limit:
\begin{align}
H(x,y) &= \lim_{\mu^2 \rightarrow 0} \int \operatorname{d}^4 u \ G_0(x,u; m)\, G_0(u,y; \sqrt{m^2 + \mu^2}) \\
& = \lim_{\mu^2 \rightarrow 0} \int \frac{\operatorname{d}^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}}{ \left(p^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon \right) \left(p^2 + m^2 + \mu^2 - i\epsilon \right) } \\
& = \lim_{\mu^2 \rightarrow 0} \int \frac{\operatorname{d}^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}}{\mu^2} \left[\frac{1}{p^2 + m^2 - i\epsilon} - \frac{1}{p^2 + m^2 + \mu^2 - i\epsilon}\right] \\
& = \lim_{\mu^2 \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\mu^2} \left[G_0(m|x-y|) - G_0\left(\sqrt{m^2 + \mu^2}|x-y|\right)\right],
\end{align}
where I used [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) in the intermediate step. Working out the final result, which can likely be done using the [Bessel function derivative identities](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29), is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @ Sean_E._Lake This is very interesting, thanks for the insight. Are you saying that I can actually take the limit $\mu^{2} \to 0$, or is this as far as I can take the computation? (it seems to me that the first term will blow up as $\mu^{2} \to 0$)

Comment: I believe you can take that limit - it's set up exactly like a derivative, which is why I suggested the dlmf identities. Note how the solvable $\Delta m^2$ perturbation produces an infinite series that shifts the squared mass, so you can think of what form a translation operator in squared mass would take, and it would involve derivatives with respect to squared mass, as we produced here.

Comment: @Sean_E._Lake I think I understand what you're saying; If I define a function $f(\mu^{2}) = G_{0}(x,y;\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}})$ such that $f(0) = G_{0}(x,y;m)$, then your above limit corresponds exactly to $- f^{\prime}(0) = - \frac{d G(x,y;\sqrt{m^{2}+\mu^{2}})}{d(\mu^{2})} \big|_{\mu^{2} = 0}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, although you don't need to define a separate function. Consider what $$-\frac{\partial G_0}{\partial m^2}$$ looks like. For more fun, you can do a chain of $n$ convolutions with $$\left(\frac{[-1]^n}{n!}\right) \frac{\partial^n G_0}{\partial [m^2]^n}.$$